# Kafka Avro what should the schema registry URL look like as getting a serialisation error

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to do a cloud guru course on confluent Kafka but a bit stuck trying to produce a message using avro, similar to what is done here https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroSpecific/Program.cs

I am getting this error when I run the code:

```
error producing message: Confluent.Kafka.ProduceException`2[System.String,confluent.io.examples.serialization.avro.User]: Local: Value serialization error
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: AvroSerializer only accepts type parameters of int, bool, double, string, float, long, byte[], instances of ISpecificRecord and subclasses of SpecificFixed.
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.SpecificSerializerImpl`1..ctor(ISchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient, Boolean autoRegisterSchema, Int32 initialBufferSize)
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.AvroSerializer`1.SerializeAsync(T value, SerializationContext context)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2.ProduceAsync(TopicPartition topicPartition, Message`2 message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2.ProduceAsync(TopicPartition topicPartition, Message`2 message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

My C# code looks like this:

```
using Avro;
using confluent.io.examples.serialization.avro;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.SchemaRegistry;
using Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes;

namespace Kafka.Avro
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {

            var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig
            {
                Url = "http://MyServerId.mylabserver.com:8081" // May need to change
            };

            var config = new ProducerConfig
            {
                BootstrapServers = "MyServerId.mylabserver.com:9092",
                Acks = Acks.All // When data is replicated to all brokers, acknowledged by all in sync replicas.
            };

            var avroSerializerConfig = new AvroSerializerConfig
            {
                // optional Avro serializer properties:
                BufferBytes = 100
            };

            using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig))
            using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, User>(config)
                    .SetValueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<User>(schemaRegistry, avroSerializerConfig))
                    .Build())
            {
                User user = new User { name = "Andrew", favorite_color = "Blue", favorite_number = 24, hourly_rate = new AvroDecimal(67.99) };
                await producer.ProduceAsync("my-avro-topic", new Message<string, User> { Key = user.name, Value = user })
                     .ContinueWith(task =>
                     {
                         if (!task.IsFaulted)
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine($"produced to: {task.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}");
                             return;
                         }
                         Console.WriteLine($"error producing message: {task.Exception.InnerException}");
                     });
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Does the schema registry look right? http://MyServerId.mylabserver.com:8081, I have just added the default port that it uses. Not sure if the error message is a red herring or not.

This is the auto generate User.cs file too:

```
namespace confluent.io.examples.serialization.avro
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using global::Avro;
    using global::Avro.Specific;
    
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("avrogen", "1.11.3")]
    public partial class User : global::Avro.Specific.ISpecificRecord
    {
        public static global::Avro.Schema _SCHEMA = global::Avro.Schema.Parse(@"{""type"":""record"",""name"":""User"",""namespace"":""confluent.io.examples.serialization.avro"",""fields"":[{""name"":""name"",""type"":""string""},{""name"":""favorite_number"",""type"":""long""},{""name"":""favorite_color"",""type"":""string""},{""name"":""hourly_rate"",""default"":null,""type"":[""null"",{""type"":""bytes"",""logicalType"":""decimal"",""precision"":4,""scale"":2}]}]}");
        private string _name;
        private long _favorite_number;
        private string _favorite_color;
        private System.Nullable<Avro.AvroDecimal> _hourly_rate;
        public virtual global::Avro.Schema Schema
        {
            get
            {
                return User._SCHEMA;
            }
        }
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this._name;
            }
            set
            {
                this._name = value;
            }
        }
        public long favorite_number
        {
            get
            {
                return this._favorite_number;
            }
            set
            {
                this._favorite_number = value;
            }
        }
        public string favorite_color
        {
            get
            {
                return this._favorite_color;
            }
            set
            {
                this._favorite_color = value;
            }
        }
        public System.Nullable<Avro.AvroDecimal> hourly_rate
        {
            get
            {
                return this._hourly_rate;
            }
            set
            {
                this._hourly_rate = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual object Get(int fieldPos)
        {
            switch (fieldPos)
            {
            case 0: return this.name;
            case 1: return this.favorite_number;
            case 2: return this.favorite_color;
            case 3: return this.hourly_rate;
            default: throw new global::Avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index " + fieldPos + " in Get()");
            };
        }
        public virtual void Put(int fieldPos, object fieldValue)
        {
            switch (fieldPos)
            {
            case 0: this.name = (System.String)fieldValue; break;
            case 1: this.favorite_number = (System.Int64)fieldValue; break;
            case 2: this.favorite_color = (System.String)fieldValue; break;
            case 3: this.hourly_rate = (System.Nullable<Avro.AvroDecimal>)fieldValue; break;
            default: throw new global::Avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index " + fieldPos + " in Put()");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "look right"? It's a REST API. Use your browser to interact with it

Comment: Why would I use my browser to do that when I want to configure it in C# code? Are you saying we have to manually setup the object via the browser before ones code can call it!? Not even sure I have seen a portal for it so your saying if I go to that I should see a dashboard of sorts?
Look right in the sense of the port number?

Comment: There's no UI builtin to the schema registry. You don't need to use a browser. Postman or any http client works too. I was just asking why you think the url is incorrect?